# Как реализовать выделение определенных слов (или символов) в виджете QTextEdit?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtextedit, qplaintextedit, qsyntaxhighlighter

Как реализовать выделение определенных слов (или символов) в `QTextEdit`
без потери фокуса ввода или смены позиции курсора?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как вариант:

editor_2.py

```
from PyQt5 import Qt
import syntax_2

app    = Qt.QApplication([])
editor = Qt.QPlainTextEdit()

font = Qt.QFont()
font.setPointSize(12)
editor.setFont(font)

highlight = syntax_2.PythonHighlighter(editor.document())
editor.show()
editor.resize(700, 400)

# Загрузите что-нибудь (например, editor_2.py) в редактор для демонстрации. 
infile = open('editor_2.py', 'r')
editor.setPlainText(infile.read())

app.exec_()
```

syntax_2.py

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

def format(color, style=''):
    """ Верните QTextCharFormat с указанными атрибутами. """
    _color = QColor()
    _color.setNamedColor(color)

    _format = QTextCharFormat()
    _format.setForeground(_color)
    if 'bold' in style:
        _format.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold)
    if 'italic' in style:
        _format.setFontItalic(True)

    return _format


# Синтаксические стили, которые могут использоваться 
STYLES = {
    'keyword': format('blue'),
    'operator': format('red'),
    'brace': format('darkGray'),
    'defclass': format('black', 'bold'),
    'string': format('magenta'),
    'string2': format('darkMagenta'),
    'comment': format('darkGreen', 'italic'),
    'self': format('black', 'italic'),
    'numbers': format('brown'),
}


class PythonHighlighter (QSyntaxHighlighter):
    """Синтаксические маркеры для языка Python. """
    # Python keywords
    keywords = [
        'and', 'assert', 'break', 'class', 'continue', 'def',
        'del', 'elif', 'else', 'except', 'exec', 'finally',
        'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import', 'in',
        'is', 'lambda', 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'print',
        'raise', 'return', 'try', 'while', 'yield',
        'None', 'True', 'False',
    ]

    # Python operators
    operators = [
        '=',
        # Comparison
        '==', '!=', '<', '<=', '>', '>=',
        # Arithmetic
        '\+', '-', '\*', '/', '//', '\%', '\*\*',
        # In-place
        '\+=', '-=', '\*=', '/=', '\%=',
        # Bitwise
        '\^', '\|', '\&', '\~', '>>', '<<',
    ]

    # Python braces
    braces = [
        '\{', '\}', '\(', '\)', '\[', '\]',
    ]
    def __init__(self, document):
        QSyntaxHighlighter.__init__(self, document)

        self.tri_single = (QRegExp("'''"), 1, STYLES['string2'])
        self.tri_double = (QRegExp('"""'), 2, STYLES['string2'])

        rules = []

        # Keyword, operator, and brace rules
        rules += [(r'\b%s\b' % w, 0, STYLES['keyword'])
            for w in PythonHighlighter.keywords]
        rules += [(r'%s' % o, 0, STYLES['operator'])
            for o in PythonHighlighter.operators]
        rules += [(r'%s' % b, 0, STYLES['brace'])
            for b in PythonHighlighter.braces]

        # All other rules
        rules += [
            (r'\bself\b', 0, STYLES['self']),
            (r'"[^"\\]*(\\.[^"\\]*)*"', 0, STYLES['string']),
            (r"'[^'\\]*(\\.[^'\\]*)*'", 0, STYLES['string']),
            (r'\bdef\b\s*(\w+)', 1, STYLES['defclass']),
            (r'\bclass\b\s*(\w+)', 1, STYLES['defclass']),
            (r'#[^\n]*', 0, STYLES['comment']),
            (r'\b[+-]?[0-9]+[lL]?\b', 0, STYLES['numbers']),
            (r'\b[+-]?0[xX][0-9A-Fa-f]+[lL]?\b', 0, STYLES['numbers']),
            (r'\b[+-]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?:[eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?\b', 0, STYLES['numbers']),
        ]

        # Создайте QRegExp для каждого шаблона
        self.rules = [(QRegExp(pat), index, fmt)
            for (pat, index, fmt) in rules]


    def highlightBlock(self, text):
        """Применить выделение синтаксиса к данному блоку текста. """

        # Сделайте другое форматирование синтаксиса
        for expression, nth, format in self.rules:
            index = expression.indexIn(text, 0)
            while index >= 0:
                index  = expression.pos(nth)
                length = len(expression.cap(nth))
                self.setFormat(index, length, format)
                index = expression.indexIn(text, index + length)

        self.setCurrentBlockState(0)

        # Многострочные строки
        in_multiline = self.match_multiline(text, *self.tri_single)
        if not in_multiline:
            in_multiline = self.match_multiline(text, *self.tri_double)

    def match_multiline(self, text, delimiter, in_state, style):
        if self.previousBlockState() == in_state:
            start = 0
            add = 0
        else:
            start = delimiter.indexIn(text)
            add = delimiter.matchedLength()

        while start >= 0:
            end = delimiter.indexIn(text, start + add)
            if end >= add:
                length = end - start + add + delimiter.matchedLength()
                self.setCurrentBlockState(0)
            else:
                self.setCurrentBlockState(in_state)
                length = len(text) - start + add

            self.setFormat(start, length, style)
            start = delimiter.indexIn(text, start + length)

        if self.currentBlockState() == in_state:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что означает второй элемент в кортеже, который является элементов `rules`?

Comment: # Создайте QRegExp для каждого шаблона
        `self.rules = [(QRegExp(pat), index, fmt)
            for (pat, index, fmt) in rules]`